# Angular material table not rendering dataSource rows

Tags: angular, angular-material, observable

I'm using angular material table to display my dataSource that is actually an Observable but it's not working. I tried to display it outside of the table and it's working pretty well. I also tried using `changeDetectorRefs.detectChanges()`. Here's my code and the rendered component.

component.ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getCustomers();
    this.changeDetectorRefs.detectChanges();
  }
getCustomers(): void {
  this.purchaseService.getCustomersInfo()
      .subscribe(customers => {
        this.options = customers;
        this.dataSource=customers;
      });
}
displayedColumns = ['id'];
```

component.html:

```
<div *ngFor="let element of dataSource">
  {{element.id}}
</div>
<table  mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Customer Id </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}} </td>
  </ng-container>
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

rendered component:

[image]

Comment: any errors in the console

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka No errors :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you component is having `OnPush` ChangeDetectionStrategy as below

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```

Move the `this.changeDetectorRefs.detectChanges();` after setting the dataSource should fix your issue.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getCustomers();
  }
getCustomers(): void {
  this.purchaseService.getCustomersInfo()
      .subscribe(customers => {
        this.options = customers;
        this.dataSource=customers;
        this.changeDetectorRefs.detectChanges();

      });
}
displayedColumns = ['id', 'name','purchases','actions'];
```

[Working sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ddcatp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: please share a repro in stackblitz. What is your component's ChangeDetectionStrategy ?

Comment: it's ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ddcatp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html its working here with my change... if you change the changedetection to init it will not work... just try

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you don't setup columns for `'name','purchases','actions'`. Try to remove those items from the column array

```
displayedColumns = ['id'];
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sc1mwx?file=app/table-basic-example.ts)

Comment: Yes I did remove that. Sorry!

Comment: check this https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/angular-material-part-4-data-table-23874582f23a